# 2 different types of relationships between same tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Current building a system to allow the site admin to build out custom step questionnaires. The main entities are `steps` and `step_options`. `Step` is an actual step in the questionnaire `step_options` are options that can be selected in that step.

There is the notion of `sub-steps` which is how a step gets attached as a child of another step. Also `sub-steps` can be attached to a `step-option`.

This leaves me with a bit of a circular dependency between options and steps.

- A step `has-many` options
- A step can `belong-to` a step
- A step can `belong-to` an option

So a step both has many and potentially belongs to an option. Currently this is the table strcuture I have.

```
steps:
- id
- title
- parent_id (step_id)
- option_id
...

step_options:
- id
- step_id
- name
...
```

Is this the correct way to go about this? I also thought about maybe adding a middle table (option_step) for the steps than belong to an option. One of the things I'm somewhat struggling with is querying all the "root" steps, steps that don't have a `parent_id` or `option_id`, with all their options and the steps that belong to the options.

Answer (score 0):

The model seems fine.  That is a classic hierarchical model, e.g. employees and managers.

- Why do you have option_id in step table?  You can query option_step table with (where step_id = step.id) to get the multiple options.  I assume every step_option will be unique.  And step_option cannot belong to multiple steps.

The alternate will be say you have some "options" that are common for several steps.  If that is the case you can create a new object option_group as

```
id    PK of option_group
```

and then in "step_options" rathen than step_id put option_group_id.

Now in "step" table you can mention option_group_id as well.

With above you can start sharing a collection of options among several steps.

Comment: The reason for the `option_id` in the steps table is because steps can belong to `step_options`